# how to create and run docker image using Maven from dockerfile

Tags: maven, docker

I am new to docker , we are trying to create docker image for my project which we used run in simple Maven commands

```
mvn verify
```

a quick google search gives me - **Dockerfile**

```
 FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8
 COPY src C:/docker/
 COPY pom.xml C:/docker/
 COPY testng.xml C:/docker/
 RUN mvn -f C:\docker clean verify
```

my understanding from above commands are , fetch maven 3.6 image from docker hub and copy existing project files to docker container and run the maven commands .

My **POM.XML** looks like

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>sample</projectName>
                        <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports</outputDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json</cucumberOutput>
                        <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                        <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am getting an error saying

> POM file C:docker specified with the -f/--file command line argument
>   does not exist

I know that , i have problem with my docker basics , but it would be great help if you teach/tell me what could be the issue here .

Answer (score 3):

`C:/docker/` is not a valid path in `maven:3.6.0-jdk-8` image, you should have used something like `/docker/` instead.

The following `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8

COPY pom.xml /docker/
COPY testng.xml /docker/
COPY src /docker/

RUN  cd /docker/ && mvn clean verify
```

should work and run `mvn clean verify` in a Docker container. You could also set the working directory to avoid repeating `/docker/` everywhere :

```
FROM    maven:3.6.0-jdk-8

RUN     mkdir /docker

WORKDIR /docker

COPY    pom.xml .
COPY    testng.xml .
COPY    src .

RUN     mvn clean verify
```

Finally, a little trick when building with Maven like you do (outside the scope of your question but good to know) : you can significantly reduce the time of your build by downloading dependencies (using `mvn dependency:resolve`) just after the `COPY pom.xml /docker/` directive, like :

```
FROM    maven:3.6.0-jdk-8

RUN     mkdir /docker

WORKDIR /docker

COPY    pom.xml .
RUN     mvn dependency:resolve

COPY    testng.xml .
COPY    src .

RUN     mvn clean verify
```

By doing so, if you build your image twice, but just updating files in `src` folder the 2nd time, Docker will be able to use the cached layer and restart from `COPY src .` layer (therefore not re-downloading all dependencies). But of course, if you update your `pom.xml`, Docker will re-download all dependencies during the next build.

Comment: I have modified the Dockerfile as per your suggestion and try to build the image using `docker build -t sample .` . but i got the error saying "There was an error in Forked Process ,  Cannot find class in classpath: TestRunner , org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process ". Please let me know if you can help me .

Comment: This error is related to Maven, do you have the same error when building locally (not inside the container)?

Comment: It should be related to your tests configuration (`maven-surefire-plugin`, `JUnit` or `testng`). If you want more help from the community, I strongly suggest you to create another question related to this new problem and provide the entire stack trace, your POM, and anything you find interesting to describe this error.